# Need to find the attributes of an element in page for a text using selenium

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

Have a requirement here - I have a page with loads to text in it, Few of them are hypher linked.

I would like to search the text and  get the attribute of the text- just wanted to know if we have any solution for it.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please, read these links to improve your question: [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) | [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) | [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: driver.findElement(locator)).getAttribute("value") use this

Answer (score 1):

If looking for a link which comes under `anchor` tag.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Your Desired Text')]")).getAttribute("The Attribute which you want to get");
```

Answer (score 1):

**getAttribute()** :It fetch the text that containing one of any attribute in the HTML tag . Suppose there is HTML tag like

```
<input name="Name" value="selenium">selenium</input>
```

Try this code below:

`driver.findElement(By.name("Name")).getAttribute("value")`